# How to drop columns without writing every name in pandas?

Tags: pandas, python-2.7

didnt see yet how it would be because i don't want to remember the names of the columns, also maybe my columns are integer, just dropping them by their position i'm interested in, any idea? No info on the documentation

Thank you so much

**Update**

For example:

## How to drop by index in column *

```
del df[0,1,2,3]  # Doesn't work
df.drop(df.columns[[0,1,2,3]], axis=1)  # Doesn't work because it has a list instead of one column, i mean dropping multiple columns not just one
```

my DF:

```
                                     help  ... success
_links       https://opendata.com/data...  ...    True
fields       https://opendata.com/data...  ...    True
```

Comment: Use `df = df.drop(df.columns[[0, 1, 3]], axis=1)`

Comment: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'drop', i tried it, and also del df[[0,1,2,3]] but nothing

Comment: Thank you for edit. I test `df = pd.DataFrame({
        'A':list('abcdef'),
         'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
         'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
         'D':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
         'E':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
         'F':list('aaabbb')
})`

Comment: with `df = df.drop(df.columns[[0,1,2,3]], axis=1)` and working correctly.

Comment: If there are lists please change data sample for lists, be free use data sample from comment above.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60487625/how-to-drop-columns-without-writing-every-name-in-pandas?noredirect=1#comment107006102_60487625

Comment: I'm so sorry i updated the question, i was watching different dataframe (multitask problems jeje) still with the same error

Comment: Sorry, I cannot see any data in question. So how I can test your not working solution?

Comment: tested `df = pd.DataFrame({
        0:list('abcdef'),
         1:[4,5,4,5,5,4],
         7:[7,8,9,4,2,3],
         30:[1,3,5,7,1,0],
         50:[5,3,6,9,2,4],
         100:list('aaabbb')
})` and working correct

Comment: sorry column names arent numbers, i meant and updated, to deleting it by index in columns

Comment: OK, if using `print (df.columns[[0,1,2,3]])` it return first 4 columns ?

Comment: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'columns' says, im using python 27, maybe is the problem? i said on the question

Comment: I think proble is `df` is `list`, can you check it?

Comment: Ok i see the problem, casting to dataframe it makes it, thank you so much for your help, sorry for the missunderstood, multitask world problems... do the asnwer and i accept it ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem was original solution not working, because `df` was list.

So first update as list and then cast to DataFrame for avoid it.

Then working correctly:

```
#remove columns by indexing
df1 = df1.drop(df1.columns[[0, 1, 3]], axis=1)
```

Comment: better update as list and then cast to Dataframe... ;) to reproduce the error